# Swift 5.1 . Paginate firestore documents x amount of times using a UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I can currently get all the documents from a firestore collection ( it has around 20 documents total ). I want to paginate the request into a UITableView ( eg. the first request will create 3 tableView rows and every subsequent request creates 3 more. ).

The tableview methods: numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt are already set up and are working if there is no pagination ( if the entire collection is loaded in 1 go ).

```
import Firebase

class tableViewList: UITableViewController {

var queryArray: [QueryDocumentSnapshot] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {

loadDocuments()
}




func loadDocuments() {
let documents = Firestore.firestore().collection("COLLECTION NAME").order(by: 
"CITY", descending: false).limit(to: 3)
documents.addSnapshotListener { [weak self] (querySnapshot, err) in
guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
if err != nil {
print("NOT WORKING")
} else {
strongSelf.queryArray = querySnapshot?.documents  {
for fields in strongSelf.queryArray {
let data = fields.data()
// Get document fields..... ( got this to work )

DispatchQueue.main.async {
strongSelf.tableView.reloadData()
}
}
}
}
}

// Start of the issue ( paginate 3 subsequent documents )
guard let lastSequence = querySnapshot?.documents.last else {return}
let nextSequence = Firestore.firestore().collection("COLLECTION 
NAME").order(by: 
"CITY", descending: false).start(afterDocument: lastSequence)

// This is where I am stuck on how to load more documents ( and 
// tableView cells )



    }
    
}


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return queryArray.count
    
}

// the cellForRow is not important since it's out of the question 
// scope
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"ListCell", for: indexPath) as! ListCell
}


}

// I researched online this func ( willDisplay ) can create new 
// tableView cells for the pagination, but I cannot understand it 
// properly ). Not sure if this func is required.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: 
UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


// Any help will be appreciated. thanks.
```

Comment: What's your question?  And where in the world are Carmen Sandiego and lines of code for your table view?

Comment: The issue: I have a collection of documents in Firestore. I want to initially load 3 documents/tableViewcells when the tableView loads. and when the user scrolls to the last cell, I want 3 subsequent cells to be paginated each time the user scrolls to the last cell and so forth.  I'll put up the missing tableView funcs.

Comment: @ElTomato The missing tableView funcs are included.